# Calculators: Algebraic Equations and Exams

Tags: calculator

Kind of a stupid question, but I don't have much experience with calculators and thought some of you might.

I'm sitting an exam and would like to use my calculator, in particular this one:
http://www.casio-europe.com/euro/sc/technical/fx82sxplus/

The only text I've had from the school is this: "A hand held calculator may be used when answering questions on this paper but it must not be pre-programmed or able to display graphics, text or algebraic equations."

As far as I can tell I should be fine, right?

Comment: Yours is not a programmable calculator and there is no way it can display graphics. You should be fine.

Comment: While I essentially agree with Josué here, in IANAL fashion it should be pointed out that we are not your school administrators and none of us can give a definitive answer to your question.  You should absolutely contact the relevant individuals at your school (I would start with the secretary of the math department, as the most likely person to know where to route the question) and say 'this is the calculator I would like to use for this exam, is that acceptable?'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these types of questions, I would always ask my teacher/school exactly which model of calculator is OK to use. I would do this since even most teachers have no idea of what a specific calculator can or can't do. So even if you ask them to take a look at your specific calculator, they might not able to verify that it is appropriate for use.

That said, when talk is about calculators that are programmable and can show graphics I think most people usually think about calculators where you can graph functions like the [Texas Instrument TI-84](http://education.ti.com/educationportal/sites/US/productDetail/us_ti84p.html). This [HP calculator](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/215348-215348-64232-30821-215351-3235173.html?dnr=1) apparently will accept SD memory cards in some way. These calculators will usually also hold notes in some way.

From the looks of it, the calculator that you are considering does nothing in terms of graphing or storing notes or manipulating algebraic equations. The only thing your calculator might be able to store is numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You might ask the school for more specifics on what calculators are allowed.  Last time I taught Math 102 we had a list of three specific models of calculator that we allowed.  The exam invigilators don't have the time to examine each individual calculator to see what features it has.